# Найти HWND кнопки в другом приложении

Tags: c++, windows

Нужно получить HWND кнопки из другого приложения.
Приложение Anchor Wallet.

На данный момент я написал такой код:

```
HWND window = FindWindow(0, L"Anchor Wallet (1.3.1)");
HWND class_ = FindWindowEx(window, 0, L"Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", 0);
HWND btn = FindWindowEx(class_, 0, 0, L"Home");

std::cout << btn;
```

Само окно приложения и класс элементов в этом окне у меня получается найти, а вот кнопку никак не могу найти, всегда в адресе 00000000.

Я исследовал UI с помощью программы Inspect.
Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вероятнее всего, кнопку рисует и обслуживает уже движок Хромого, так что для венды она недоступна. Увы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, я даже в калькуляторе не могу кнопку найти таким образом...

Comment: В коде ищете дескриптор окна, а в программе показано дерево UI Automation.

Comment: Я не совсем вам понял, FindWindowEx ищет дескриптор через название элемента, а в программе я как раз это название и смотрю.

Comment: FindWindowEx ищет окна (HWND) по имени, но в программе показаны не окна.

Comment: Допустим. Скажите пожалуйста как мне найти элемент кнопки?

Comment: Используйте UI Automation...

Comment: @user7860670, у меня получилось нажать кнопки в калькуляторе, потому что там есть поле AutomationID, но в приложении Anhor Wallet на кнопках такого нет. Поиск по имени ничего не даёт. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? Кстати, в этом приложении 3 процесса.